# Get Hash "bytesize" in Crystal Lang

Tags: crystal-lang

My bad, there's no `Hash#bytesize` in Ruby.

I was wondering if there's a way to measure the size of any object, hash, or array.

**EDIT#2 : Evaluation of comments**

Benchmark does not seem to be deep measuring all instantiations.

```
require "benchmark"

class Animal
  def initialize
    @first_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    @last_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    @arr = Array(Int32).new
  end
end

struct Foobar
  property hola
end

animal = Benchmark.memory do
  Animal.new
end

puts "Animal used: #{animal}"

foobar = Benchmark.memory do
  Foobar.new
end

puts "Foobar used: #{foobar}"

array = Benchmark.memory do
  Array(Int32).new
end

puts "Array used: #{array}"

string = Benchmark.memory do
  String.new() + "Hello"
end

puts "String used: #{string}"
```

Outputs:

```
Animal used: 80
Foobar used: 0
Array used: 32
String used: 32
```

**EDITED**

<strike>Is there an equivalent for Ruby's `Hash#bytesize` in Crystal lang?</strike>

Ultimately, I would like to be able to measure the size of any object, hash, or array.

Comment: Which language has `Hash#bytesize`? Because Ruby 2.6 doesn't seem to be it: `undefined method \`bytesize' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @JonneHaß my bad. Such a method doesn't exist in Ruby. I know `String#bytesize` exists in Crystal but I'm looking for something that would give me the allocated memory of any object. I know it's a pointer but it would be great to be able to follow the pointers all the way to determine how much memory we're allocating.

Comment: The problem is that the answer is highly ambiguous. Very simplified, say we do `h1 = {a: 1}; h2 = {a: h1[:a]}` and assume allocating a hash is 4 bytes, a pointer to some chunk of memory, 4 bytes for a symbol and 4 bytes for 32 bit number. The memory usage of the program is not `(4 + 4 + 4) * 2` since both hashes reference the same values. In fact it's not even allocating `4 + 4` at runtime since `:a` and `4` are just constants in the programs code.

Comment: Maybe this is an XY question and you're more interested in the amount of allocation a particular section of your program does? For this we have https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.30.1/Benchmark.html#memory(&block)-instance-method

Comment: Erm, it looks a bit weird... It's not measuring instantiations of objects and strings contained within for example. I'll post an example in my question.

Comment: It only measures changes in heap memory. That's why the struct is `0`, because it's allocated on the stack, and also that's why any strings don't count, because they're constants referenced from the program code. Also if you have a larger block of code under measurement where it does a couple of allocations but also releases objects again and there's a GC phase inbetween, it only measures the net increase.

Comment: The answer is a bit ambiguous. For example for an Array you might want to count the size of the array itself: size and capacity 4 bytes each, then the buffer which is a pointer to 8 bytes, and then the allocated buffer size. But do you want to count the size of each element in the array? Recursively or not? Or let's take a Hash. Previously it was implemented as a linked list. How do you know that to compute the memory size? Now it's not a linked list so the computation should be done differently. I guess the real question is: what do you need this for?